# Colonizing a planet with a giant red fungus

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book many (20-30) years ago about a habitable planet where a crew was dropped with everything they needed to begin colonization. They may or may not have been mining anything. There were a number of crew members, IDK 80 to 100. A few years later more people came on a different ship as planned just a couple years or less to continue colonization. (The alien landscape was described completely and exquisitely. Everything on the planet had a common language in light and color and interconnectedness.)

The next ship comes and only one person is left. A lot happens that I am leaving out, of course, but it turns out there was a giant carpet fungus, a beautiful red color with a delightful texture and scent. Everyone would go there in their time off, together and separately and basically bliss out on this gorgeous carpet.

A 3rd ship comes near the end of the book about 20 years from the first ship.

Turns out the planet didn't feel the need to be exploited and so created a situation in which the "problem" was eaten, naturally and humanely (so to speak).

It was a book not a short story or novella. The amount of time it took for the second crew to arrive was 3 to 5 years, and the third ship arrived 10 or more years later. The information I left out are things I don't recall like names and relationships. Also, there were a number of excursions and picnics and outings and dating one another that were described vaguely. It turned out everyone wasn't as into dating and outings as they were into going to the fungus.

The book was paper back and probably pulp but a full length story. There was a lot of description and study of the planet and the language. I do read books by linguists, it's possible it was written by a linguistics person.  I read the book 20-30 years ago and the book could possibly be as old as Asimov but was NOT Asimov. The people in the book never figure out what is going on. But they do abandon the planet.

Comment: Was this a novel or a short story? It doesn't sound as if there is enough content for a full length novel.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: It was a full length book. A lot of the writing was the discription of the planet and her language, throughout. I put more detail in the main body of my question. I don't remember more.